# iPhone OpenGL : Data Type Question

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, types

I want to store an array of floats that's also an array.

So I want to store an array of float[3] (this contains x,y,sizex,sizey) to use with OpenGL

What's the best way of doing this as using standard ObjectiveC arrays feels like a slow solution.

I am going through the array on every draw call to check for collision with objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an array of GLfloats in standard C, that will probably be your best bet performance wise.

Comment: How do you declare an array of glFloats thats also an array?

Comment: Do you mean an array within an array?  GLfloat myCoords[10][10]; would do that, this of course is static you could also use alloc and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

GLfloat is the best way to go on IOS when you are using opengl.